# Get the filename in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have **LAPP.NT.APC.HIST.zip** file, I'm extracting,

$ **unzip LAPP.NT.APC.HIST.ZIP**
 
Archive:  LAPP.NT.APC.HIST.EXT.AUDIT.MTLY.ZIP
PKZIP for z/OS by PKWARE
  inflating: **LAPP.NT.APC.HIST.EXT.AUDIT1**
  inflating: **LAPP.NT.APC.HIST.EXT.AUDIT2**

how can get the specific *inflating* filename? If I get the filename, I want to assign into one variable like, How to do?

***filename=`find . -type f  -name "*.*"`***
**echo $filename**

Thanks to @Zlemini , @jszakmeister,

Comment: Sorry, it is unclear what you actually ask.

Comment: When you UNZIP, you direct the _inflated_ results to a specific folder. The result of the UNZIP may be a flat list of files or a tree of folders and files. You can simple scan the contents of the target folder (and any sub-folders in a hierarchical mode) and collect the names of the files found there. If you are looking for a specific filename, then do the same but providing (at least) a seed of the filename.

Comment: I m looking for a zip have specific filenames only

Answer (score 3):

`unzip -l filename.zip` will print the names, uncompressed file sizes and modification dates and times contained in an archive without inflating it.

`unzip -Z1  peace.zip` is more suitable here i think as it will display filenames only.

Here are the filenames contained in a zip file assigned to a variable:

`files_zipped=$(unzip -Z1  filename.zip)`

Comment: Thanks, but  inflating filenames I want to assign into one variable, How to do?

Comment: You will need to parse the output of `unzip -l`, example: `zipfile_content=$(unzip -l filename.zip | awk '{print $NF}')`

Comment: Please explain above command, if **echo $zipped_gif** I'm not getting filename?

Comment: updated answer to address this

Comment: I'd use `unzip -Z -1 filename.zip`... it avoids the extra awk processing because it will only print the filename.

Comment: Yes agreed, just posted that.

Comment: Wowww!!! Great !! but one more small question if i am extracting multiple .zip file at a time using below query,

for i in *zip; do unzip "$i" & done 


how can I get? Please help.

Comment: Some pointers on that here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14120/extract-only-a-specific-file-from-a-zipped-archive-to-a-given-directory. Give it a try and open a question with your efforts if you run into an issue.